# Error redirection in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing a browser-like application in android using WebView.
While loading the URL, I want to display a specific page/message/toast whenever server returns 404 response. I tried using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but it can filter URLs based on URL string only. Is there any good way to get the server's response code within `WebViewClient` or `WebChromeClient` (without loading the URL twice)?

Comment: Be more explicit. You don't intercept the url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading ?

Comment: @Snicolas all i want is to get the event when 404 error is obtained.

Comment: Webviewclient has a method onPageError or something like this. Is it what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997677/android-webview-onreceivederror

Answer (score -1, accepted):

override the method `onReceivedError` of `WebViewclient`

Comment: Where is there an `onPageError` method in `WebViewClient`? It's not in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: its actually `onReceivedError`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (I've updated my answer)