# How to handle switching WebView url if got any error result?

Tags: java, android, webview

My application often used `WebView` as core. My websites are deployed in 3 different host for increase the availability of service. How to handle switching the websites efficiently if one of them is down or cannot reach. Assume the websites url are `url1`, `url2` and `url3` respectively. For Example if `webview.loadUrl(url1);` bring any error result, It should switch to another.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Android WebView onReceivedError()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997677/android-webview-onreceivederror) 
may be will help you.

when you use **onReceivedError** to handle your problem, you could switch you url in the override function.