# WebView's onReceivedError not triggered when internet connection is lost in Android app

Tags: java, android-webview

I'm encountering an issue with the `onReceivedError` method of the `WebViewClient` in my Android application. I've implemented the `onReceivedError` method to handle errors when loading web resources, including cases where the internet connection is lost. However, the `onReceivedError` method doesn't seem to be triggered when the internet connection is lost.

Here's how I've implemented the `onReceivedError` method within my WebViewClient:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        private void stopLoadingAndShowFallbackImage(WebView view) {
            view.stopLoading();
            showFallbackImage(view);
        }

        private boolean shouldShowFallbackImage(@NonNull String url) {
            return url.contains("streets-staging.portlmedia.com") ||
                    url.contains("streets.portlmedia.com") ||
                    url.contains("localhost:3000");
        }

        private void checkInternetAndReconnectAfterDelay(WebView view, final String url) {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                boolean isMainPageReachable = isMainPageReachable();
                if (isMainPageReachable) {
                    mainHandler.post(() -> loadUrlInWebView(view, url));
                } else {
                    mainHandler.postDelayed(() -> checkInternetAndReconnectAfterDelay(view, url), 3000);
                }
            });
        }

        private void loadUrlInWebView(WebView view, final String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        private boolean isMainPageReachable() {
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
            try {
                httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(mainPageUrl).openConnection();
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                int responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();
                return responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 300;
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (httpUrlConnection != null) {
                    httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }

        private void showFallbackImage(WebView view) {
            String htmlContent = "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"><style>html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #272727; } .overlay { position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }</style></head><body><img class=\"overlay\" src=\"file:///android_res/drawable/bg.png\"></body></html>";
            view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/", htmlContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceivedError: " + request.getUrl() + ", " + error.getDescription());
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            if (shouldShowFallbackImage(url)) {
                stopLoadingAndShowFallbackImage(view);
                checkInternetAndReconnectAfterDelay(view, mainPageUrl);
            }
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }
    });
```

The onReceivedError method is supposed to be called when there is an error loading a resource in the WebView, including cases where the internet connection is lost. However, it doesn't seem to be working in my case.

I've also verified that I have the necessary permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

What could be causing the onReceivedError method not to be triggered when the internet connection is lost? Is there something wrong with how I've implemented it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Who would send that error that you dont receive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android WebView onReceivedError()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997677/android-webview-onreceivederror)

Comment: @blackapps loss of internet connection

Comment: You still did not tell who would send that error.